# ¿Cómo soluciono un timeout con listas extensas en python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy tratando de realizar un programa que reciba una lista de numeros ej: 100 435 200 3432 42423 1221 9999 -1223 e imprimia "SI" si algun numero de esta secuencia con otro de como resultado 1000 en caso contrario imprimir "NO". El programa trabaja muy bien pero con listas extensas me tira time out.

El código:

```
`
tupla = tuple([int(x) for x in input().split()])
for i in range(len(tupla)-1):
    for j in range(i+1,len(tupla)):
        if tupla[i]+tupla[j] == 1000:
            print('SI')
            exit()
print('NO')
```

`

Comment: al probar tu codigo me funciona perfectamente con listas bastante largas tanto en win10 como en linux

Comment: intenta probar con 999999 numeros

Comment: ¿Cómo es eso de que te da _timeout_? El programa puede tardar lo que sea, poco o mucho. Mientras no haya "nadie" midiendo si tarda demasiado, el concepto de _timeout_ no se aplica. ¿Dónde lo estás ejecutando? ¿Es algún sistema de verificación automatizada que pone un tiempo límite para que el programa termine?

Comment: Por otro lado, ya que tienes un bucle dentro de otro, meter 999999 números implica aproximadamente 999999**2 iteraciones, que son bastantes... (999998000001 para ser exactos). Aún si logras hacer un millón de iteraciones por segundo, tardarías en completarlas todas 999998 segundos, que son unos once días!

Comment: ¿es un haiku? si lo es me interesa resolverlo

Answer (score 1):

Del modo que lo has puesto realizas len(lista)^2 operaciones para comprobar los números

en lugar de eso es mucho mas practico y eficiente ver que número es necesario para alcanzar 1000 y ver si este se encuentra en la lista, adicionalmente se puede eliminar los números duplicados reduciendo así la lista y mirar si hay mas de un 500

```
from random import randrange
from time import time
start = time()
lista = list()
for i in range(9999999):
    if i in range(0, 999999999, 1000000):
        print(f"voy por {i}")
    lista.append(randrange(-9999999, 9999999))
print(f'lista lista en {int(time() - start)} segundos')
def hasta_mil(valor):
    result = 0
    if valor > 1000:
        result = -(valor - 1000)
    elif valor < 0:
        result = 1000 + valor
    elif valor < 1000:
        result = 1000 - valor
    return result
da_mil = False
start2 = time()
cuenta500 = lista.count(500)
if cuenta500 > 1:
    print(f"Se han encontrado {cuenta500} valores de 500, su suma da 1000")
    da_mil = True
else:
    largo = len(lista)
    print(f"Eliminando duplicados de la lista tiene {largo} elementos")
    lista2 = set(lista)
    print(f"Duplicados eliminados en {int(time() - start2)} segundos, eliminados {largo - len(lista2)} elementos, "
          f"quedan {len(lista2)} se ha reducido un {int(100*(len(lista) - len(lista2))/len(lista))}%")

    for i in lista2:
        if hasta_mil(i) in lista2:
            da_mil = True
            break

print(f"alguno da mil {'SI' if da_mil else 'NO'} realizado en {int(time() - start)} segundos")
```

con este código le cuesta mas generar la lista que comprobarla una lista de 10 millones de elementos la genera en unos 15 segundos y la resuelve en menos de 5, he hecho una comprobación y recorrer todos los elementos le ha llevado apenas 20 segundos